# Apache NIFI Jon is not terminating automatically

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to Apache NIFI tool. I am trying to import data from mongo db and put that data into the HDFS. I have created 2 processors one for MongoDB and second for HDFS and I configured them correctly. The job is running successfully and storing the data into HDFS but the job should terminate automatically on success. But it is not, and creating too many files in HDFS. I want to know how to make **On Demand Job** in NIFI and how to determine that a job is successfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetMongo` will continue to pull data from MongoDB based on the provided properties such as `Query`, `Projection`, `Limit`. It has no way of tracking the execution process, at least for now. What you can do, however, is changing the `Run Schedule` and/or `Scheduling Strategy`. You can find them by right clicking on the processor and clicking `Configure`. By default, `Run Schedule` will be 0 sec which means running continuously. Changing it to, say, `60 min` will make the processor run every one hour. This will still read the same documents from MongoDB again every one hour but since you have mentioned that you just want to run it only once, I'm suggesting this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you help me how to pass query inside Getmongo I am trying to pass simple db.collection.find() but it always showing the exclamation mark.

Comment: The query is expected to be in a valid *JSON* format not the Mongo shell query. BTW, the `Query` property is optional and if omitted, the entire collection will be queried and returned as flowfiles. Sample query should be like: {a: 1, b:2}