# Apache Niffi getMongo Processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new in niffi i am using getMongo to extract document from mongodb but same result is coming again and again but the result of query is only 2 document the query is {"qty":{$gt:10}}

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question regarding this. Let me quote what I had said there:

"`GetMongo` will continue to pull data from MongoDB based on the provided properties such as Query, Projection, Limit. It has no way of tracking the execution process, at least for now. What you can do, however, is changing the `Run Schedule` and/or `Scheduling Strategy`. You can find them by right clicking on the processor and clicking Configure. By default, `Run Schedule` will be `0 sec` which means running continuously. Changing it to, say, `60 min` will make the processor run every one hour. This will still read the same documents from MongoDB again every one hour but since you have mentioned that you just want to run it only once, I'm suggesting this approach."

The question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317897/apache-nifi-jon-is-not-terminating-automatically/49350433#49350433).

Comment: is there any other way to import data  form mongodb without the above problemn

Comment: Through NiFi? I'm afraid not. There are other utilities outside NiFi that lets you import MongoDB documents