# NiFi GetMongo fetches data forever

Tags: apache-nifi

I have millions of records in MongoDB and I want to use NiFi to move data. Here is the scenario I want to run:

1) I will setup NiFi

2) NiFi will automatically fetch records with batches of 100 records.

3) Once it is done, it will fetch when a new entry is added.

I tried to apply this scenario with a small MongoDB collection (fetch from mongo and store as a file) and I saw that NiFi is repeating the process forever and it is duplicating the records.

Here is the flow I created on NiFi:
[image: a simple flow for NiFi]

Are there are any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `GetMongo` doesn't have state tracking capabilities. There are similar questions where I have explained about it. You can find them:

- [Apache NIFI Jon is not terminating automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317897/apache-nifi-jon-is-not-terminating-automatically/49350433#49350433)
- [Apache Niffi getMongo Processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726998/apache-niffi-getmongo-processor/49732619#49732619)

Comment: if i set batch size 100, will it fetch by 100 and 100? without trying to fetch all rows at once?